# Did Tolkien ever discuss the inconsistent number of recorded Human and Elven relationships

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In Tolkien's legendarium he was very clear that there were three unions of elves and men. Which were those of:

- Beren and Lúthien
- Tuor and Idril
- Aragorn and Arwen

Tolkien also describes at least two other potential/actual relationships between elves and men.

- Túrin and Finduilas
- Imrazôr and Mithrellas

The union of Imrazôr and Mithrellas, ultimately led to the birth of Imrahil, the Prince of Dol Amroth, who was an important figure at the end of the third age.

Did Tolkien ever explain or discuss these other unions between men and elves and the inconsistency this causes with the statement that there were only three unions?

Comment: *Eldar* and men

Comment: Uh, Galadriel and me.  Sadly, died during childbirth. 

Answer (score 3):

There's (probably) no inconsistency.

The three "important" unions involved the two families from which Elros descended, and two of his descendants.

There was no "union" between Túrin and Finduilas; she loved him, but he did not reciprocate.

Mithrellas was a Silvan Elf, *possibly* one of the Eldar, but not one of the two more important branches (the Noldor and the Sindar) in Middle-earth. She was either one of the Nandor (those of the Teleri that abandoned the Great March) or one of other Moriquendi that never started on the Great March.

Comment: All Sindar were considered Eldar, as a branch of Teleri.  The Eldar included all Elven peoples who participated in the Great Journey, even those that stopped part way.

Comment: The term for what you are describing is *Calaquendi* or "High Elves", but Lúthien is not one of them.

Comment: Yeah, kind of ruins my distinction for Mithrellas, who was (probably) one of the Nandor. I wonder if the most that can be said is that she and Imrazor were not an "important" union, in that their offspring did not involve an ancestor or (direct) descendant of the House of Elros.

Comment: Arwen was half-elven, so perhaps she and Aragorn shouldn't count.

Comment: @suchiuomizu: I don't think the Silvan Elves were counted as Sindar, because they left the Great Journey too early. They also did have their own language, separate from Sindarin. But I guess merely starting out made you one of the Eldar?

Comment: @suchiuomizu: Checking LotR Appendix F, Mithrellas is almost certainly by the definition there not one of the Eldar: *The Elves far back in the Elder Days became divided into two main branches: the West-elves (the Eldar) and the East-elves. **Of the latter kind were most of the elven-folk of Mirkwood and Lórien**.*

Comment: The Silvan Elves, though, are stated in the "Index of Names" in *The Silmarillion* as being Nandorin Elves, not Moriquendi. I'm not sure how (or if) those two passages can be reconciled.

Comment: @chepner: In The Silmarillion, the Sindar and the Silvan Elves are both accounted Moriquendi; this is said in the very beginning of Chapter 10, and it's more particularly defined in Chapter 3 (t"he Umanyar and the Avari alike"). Eldar is a different distinction. We're told that Eldar was the name Orome assigned them, but that it was "after borne only by those who followed him on the road". Going by Appendix F, it seems the best way to reconcile this is to say following him only as far as the Misty Mountains did not qualify you.

Comment: @chepner: There is an early passage In Volume X of HoME, Chapter 3, which seems to exclude the SIlvan Elves as Eldar: "They are not counted among the Eldar, nor yet among the Avari. The Nandor who turn back they were called."